# passing nonconstatnt value to template in c++

Tags: c++

Question : I need a method to use x variable as input for xSet() methods. Currently the compiler is giving an error saying that

> the value of 'x' is not usable in a constant expression

I know what it means. But i want to know if there is any method by which i can pass x value to xSet method.

Thank You !!!

```
template <int t_ID>
static size_t xSet()
{
    return t_ID;
}

int main()
{

    for (int x = 0; x <14 ; x++)
    {
        xSet<x>();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What you want. How you use it?

Comment: Well, you can write an overloaded version `int xSet(int x) { return x; }` and use that. Or you can write a switch with 15 case statements, converting each runtime value back into a compile-time one like `case 7: xSet<7>(); break;`. Or you can suse a compile-time iteration instead of a `for` loop. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It is a small part of very big implementation. Basically it is a prototype and there are 1000's of x value.

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ where is the duplicate question ?

Comment: Are you trying to convert runtime arguments into compile-time arguments?

Comment: @Mandeep The answer at the linked question shows you how you can do that. That the question isn't exactly the same as yours is irrelevant.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That question is not the same question which i asked there is no constant to non constant or vice versa taking place. The only similarity is he is using template and i am. This part does not make questions same

Comment: You cannot instantiate templates at runtime.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ can you remove the similarity part which you put on my question

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're trying to do is call a specialisation of a template function by selecting it with a runtime integer?

In which case, you need something like this:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <int t_ID>
static std::size_t xSet()
{
    return t_ID;
}

template<int...Is>
constexpr auto make_xSet_calls(std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>)
{
    using function_sig = std::size_t (*)();
    return std::array<function_sig, sizeof...(Is)>
    {{
        &xSet<Is>...
    }};
}; 

int main()
{

    auto constexpr limit = 14;
    for (int x = 0; x < limit ; x++)
    {
        std::cout << make_xSet_calls(std::make_integer_sequence<int, limit>())[x]() << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank You but can you tell me what is the use of integer sequence. wont it be the same if i use switch case in for loop for 14 variations ? Why I am asking this is because just to clearify the basic idea that i would be letting compiler know the size before running the function. Cant i some how make compiler wait till i run the programme. Thank You !!!

Comment: have a look at the documentation. It's quite an advanced subject: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence

Comment: That what i mean that i dont want to tell the compiler until i run the programme. The similar thing shown above can be done by a switch command in for loop with 14 variation for example. Still Thank You for your help !!!!

Comment: @Mandeep, templates are transformed into "real code" that is then compiled. Compilation only happens at compile time. If a template argument is not known until the program is run, the program must have already been compiled. It is too late to use a template at that point. You will have to find another way.